# Difference between 'multi output' vs 'raw' in keras 'flow_from_dataframe'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm not sure about when to use `raw` vs `multi output` in the keras [flow_from_dataframe](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdataframe-method) `class_mode` parameter, as by the looks of it, they both provide a way to classifying data with multiple labels. Suppose say I have a dataframe with the image path as well as two columns/classes with labels for each given image, and I would like to create a model which classifies the images based on those classes, which `class_mode` would I use, and when would I use the other one?

Edit: attached an image of the dataframe I'm using

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could provide an example of the data you have a question about. Can you include the dataframe of what you have in your question?

Comment: @TCArlen Thanks. I have updated my post accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `class_mode="raw"` when the label column you're using has the actual raw class values that you intend to use as the training label. For example, if you're doing a regression task or ordinal regression and you have floating point numbers or integers as your columns. In that case, you must make sure that the actual numerical values are what you want your final labels to be.

In your case, it looks like you have text labels of different classes, so you have a multi-class, multi-label classification problem, and therefore you must use `class_mode="multi_output"` to transform the y-values correctly with multiple labels.